# About Gtk Dialog box Behavior

Tags: gtk

About Gtk Dialog box Behavior...

I am using GtkBuilder +Glade to display a top level window and dialogs in it...

```
builder = gtk_builder_new();
gtk_builder_add_from_file( builder, "test.glade", NULL );
windowPtr = GTK_WIDGET( gtk_builder_get_object( m_builder, "window_main"));
```

on clicking on button i am opening one dialog box which is in other glade file.... 
after closing the dialog box control gets return to main window....

but when i click again on button to open dialog box.. it opens the dialog box but dialog box does not show any child widgets in it (it is just a empty window).. why this is happening?

I am not handling close event on dialog!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In glade, set the callback for "delete-event" of your GtkDialog to [`gtk_widget_hide_on_delete`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-hide-on-delete). This will then *hide* your dialog instead of *destroying* it.

Also, you will need to add this line to your program:
[`gtk_builder_signals_connect( m_builder, NULL )`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkBuilder.html#gtk-builder-connect-signals)